# Trying to build an SSH honeypot in C

Tags: c, ssh, honeypot

I'm trying to write a honeypot in C to replicate an SSH session. I'm aiming for a low interaction honeypot (similar to Kippo).

The idea is: client connects to honeypot via SSH, honeypot then understands and responds to pre-defined commands (e.g. wget, env etc).

The bit I'm stuck on is creating the initial SSH connection. I've read through the RFC for SSH to get an understanding of how SSH session are initiated. Then I've been looking at the libraries OpenSSH, libssh and libssh2 - but I can't see how to initiate an SSH session similar to sshd.

Not sure if I can use the sshd service to create the SSH session and then run the honeypot from that?

Hope that makes sense. Any help on this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you looked at the Kippo source to see what they do?

Comment: @danfuzz The Kippo source uses the Twisted library http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/conch/examples/sshsimpleserver.py which has its own ssh transport protocol implementation http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/browser/trunk/twisted/conch/ssh/connection.py

I'm currently looking into libssh which seems to allow a server implementation

Answer (score 0):

Think I found what I was looking for: libssh. There's a good example on their github page of how to implement an ssh daemon in C: https://github.com/substack/libssh/blob/master/examples/samplesshd.c

For a basic SSH honeypot implementation in C there's project on github called sshpot by Pete Morris (https://github.com/PeteMo/sshpot):

```
#include "config.h"
#include "auth.h"

#include <libssh/libssh.h>
#include <libssh/server.h>

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <getopt.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

#define MINPORT 0
#define MAXPORT 65535

/* Global so they can be cleaned up at SIGINT. */
static ssh_session session;
static ssh_bind sshbind;


/* Print usage information to `stream', exit with `exit_code'. */
static void usage(FILE *stream, int exit_code) {
    fprintf(stream, "Usage: sshpot [-h] [-p <port>]\n");
    fprintf(stream,
            "   -h  --help          Display this usage information.\n"
            "   -p  --port <port>   Port to listen on; defaults to 22.\n");
    exit(exit_code);
}


/* Return the c-string `p' as an int if it is a valid port 
 * in the range of MINPORT - MAXPORT, or -1 if invalid. */
static int valid_port(char *p) {
    int port;
    char *endptr;

    port = strtol(p, &endptr, 10);
    if (port >= MINPORT && port <= MAXPORT && !*endptr && errno == 0) 
        return port;

    return -1;
}


/* Signal handler for cleaning up after children. We want to do cleanup
 * at SIGCHILD instead of waiting in main so we can accept multiple
 * simultaneous connections. */
static int cleanup(void) {
    int status;
    int pid;
    pid_t wait3(int *statusp, int options, struct rusage *rusage);

    while ((pid=wait3(&status, WNOHANG, NULL)) > 0) {
        if (DEBUG) { printf("process %d reaped\n", pid); }
    }

    /* Re-install myself for the next child. */
    signal(SIGCHLD, (void (*)())cleanup);

    return 0;
}


/* SIGINT handler. Cleanup the ssh* objects and exit. */
static void wrapup(void) {
    ssh_disconnect(session);
    ssh_bind_free(sshbind);
    ssh_finalize();
    exit(0);
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int port = DEFAULTPORT;

    /* Handle command line options. */
    int next_opt = 0;
    const char *short_opts = "hp:";
    const struct option long_opts[] = {
        { "help",   0, NULL, 'h' },
        { "port",   1, NULL, 'p' },
        { NULL,     0, NULL, 0   }
    };

    while (next_opt != -1) {
        next_opt = getopt_long(argc, argv, short_opts, long_opts, NULL);
        switch (next_opt) {
            case 'h':
                usage(stdout, 0);
                break;

            case 'p':
                if ((port = valid_port(optarg)) < 0) {
                    fprintf(stderr, "Port must range from %d - %d\n\n", MINPORT, MAXPORT);
                    usage(stderr, 1);
                }
                break;

            case '?':
                usage(stderr, 1);
                break;

            case -1:
                break;

            default:
                fprintf(stderr, "Fatal error, aborting...\n");
                exit(1);
        }
    }

    /* There shouldn't be any other parameters. */
    if (argv[optind]) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid parameter `%s'\n\n", argv[optind]);
        usage(stderr, 1);
    }

    /* Install the signal handlers to cleanup after children and at exit. */
    signal(SIGCHLD, (void (*)())cleanup);
    signal(SIGINT, (void(*)())wrapup);

    /* Create and configure the ssh session. */
    session=ssh_new();
    sshbind=ssh_bind_new();
    ssh_bind_options_set(sshbind, SSH_BIND_OPTIONS_BINDADDR, LISTENADDRESS);
    ssh_bind_options_set(sshbind, SSH_BIND_OPTIONS_BINDPORT, &port);
    ssh_bind_options_set(sshbind, SSH_BIND_OPTIONS_HOSTKEY, "ssh-rsa");
    ssh_bind_options_set(sshbind, SSH_BIND_OPTIONS_RSAKEY,RSA_KEYFILE);

    /* Listen on `port' for connections. */
    if (ssh_bind_listen(sshbind) < 0) {
        printf("Error listening to socket: %s\n",ssh_get_error(sshbind));
        return -1;
    }
    if (DEBUG) { printf("Listening on port %d.\n", port); }

    /* Loop forever, waiting for and handling connection attempts. */
    while (1) {
        if (ssh_bind_accept(sshbind, session) == SSH_ERROR) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error accepting a connection: `%s'.\n",ssh_get_error(sshbind));
            return -1;
        }
        if (DEBUG) { printf("Accepted a connection.\n"); }

        switch (fork())  {
            case -1:
                fprintf(stderr,"Fork returned error: `%d'.\n",-1);
                exit(-1);

            case 0:
                exit(handle_auth(session));

            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```